# The interaction with the website

Tags: android

The website has a counter reputation.Im have two links. First link increment reputation counter, second decrement reputation counter. How im can go to the link without opening a browser to increase or decrease the reputation counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to post to the link.

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

You probably wont need the name value pairs to have anything so you can probably delete everything in between the Add your data and Execute HTTP Post Request comments but you will need to change the path when creating the HttpPost.

Code taken from [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)